# Is it possible to see which tables have had their data modified yesterday?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

We have a Microsoft SQL Server database. We're not manually keeping track of when edits or updates to the data in the tables were made. Is there still a way to find out which tables have had their data updated within, say, the last 24 hours?

Comment: There must be a journal log somewhere?

Comment: Consider using Temporal Tables.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah There's a transaction log, sure, but it is cumbersome to read (many vendors have tried and failed), and also it gets cleared out frequently depending on recovery model, backup schedule, checkpoints, etc. Basically, no, it is not a reliable way for any practical duration.

Comment: Translog is not bad if you just wanna see who did *something* to some table, saved my bacon a few times. It might get cleared, but if you have decent backups, you should be able to restore the log to some point in time and check it out. Read about fn_dblog. I think it shouldn't be overused in prod, cause it leaks a thread if my memory serves me correct

Comment: @siggemannen True, however: (a) most folks asking questions here, I would venture, do not have anything remotely close to what you and I would consider "decent backups" :-) (b) even if they do, it is often very difficult to propose restoring a copy of the backup to a point in time. Here at Stack there are some databases where it would be very challenging to even find a place to do that on a whim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server does not track this information by default, though there is a way to see if any updates have been *attempted* since a given point in time using the dynamic management view [`sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-index-usage-stats-transact-sql).

```
DECLARE @cutoff datetime = DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE());

SELECT [schema] = s.name,
       [object] = o.name
FROM sys.objects AS o
INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
ON o.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
WHERE EXISTS -- since we don't need 8 rows if there are 8 indexes
(
  SELECT 1 
    FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats AS ius
    WHERE ius.[object_id] = o.[object_id]
    AND ius.last_user_update >= @cutoff
);
```

Some caveats:

- This doesn't mean the data *actually changed* - this just reflects the latest update *attempt*.
- You can't see *just yesterday* and not include today, or know if a row was *only* updated today and not yesterday - there isn't a running history, just the most recent update.
- You can't see how many updates were attempted in that range, or how many rows were affected, never mind which rows.
- You won't see any information for spatial or memory-optimized indexes.
- This view gets cleared out on service restarts, failovers, offline/online, and [some other events (version-specific)](https://littlekendra.com/2016/03/07/sql-server-2016-rc0-fixes-index-usage-stats-bug-missing-indexes-still-broken/).

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a Change Data Capture which follows up on any modified, delete updated data. You can also set up the time frame in which you wish to track this information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-data-capture-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).